# Value as hyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

This is my third topic on your wonderful forum - I've already gotten very useful answers and help!

My next issue is about "hyperlinking" values to their cells of origin. I made a screenshot of a data filtering in my file.

[image: screenshot]

The terms appear in a filtered list. When clicking a term, one can see the tab & cell is has been extracted from. What I need is this information to be converted into a hyperlink, so that the user may click the term and be sent right to the tab where he can find more information on it.

I hope this is clear enough... :/ Could you help me again please?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: Hi Mathieu, 
Thanks for your input, but in fact I'm not sure how I could have made my question clearer? I did describe the desired behavior and issue, but I couldn't insert any code as this is precisely what I'm looking for: the code. I've no idea about how to do it... Sorry if it wasn't ok, I'll try to rephrase it as I answer people (provided someone does answer ;) )

Comment: Yeah, SO isn't a code-writing service. See [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: All right... Sorry. Should I better delete my post?

Answer (score 2):

#### How to Create a Bookmark to the Same Worksheet

A bookmark in Excel is similar to a hyperlink except that it is used to create a link to a specific area on the current worksheet or to a different worksheet within the same Excel file.

While hyperlinks use file names to create links to other Excel files, bookmarks use cell references and worksheet names to create links.

The following example creates a bookmark to a different location in the same Excel worksheet.

1. Type a name in a cell that will act as the anchor text for the bookmark and press **Enter**.
2. Click on that cell to make it the active cell.
3. Open the **Insert Hyperlink** dialog box.
4. Click on the **This Document** tab.
5. Under the **Type the cell reference**, enter a cell reference to a different location on the same worksheet – such as "Z100."
6. Click **OK** to complete the bookmark and close the dialog box.
7. The anchor text in the worksheet cell should now be blue in color and underlined indicating that it contains a bookmark.
8. Click on the bookmark and the active cell cursor moves to the cell reference entered for the bookmark.

[Reference](https://www.lifewire.com/hyperlinks-bookmarks-and-mailto-shortcuts-excel-3123635)

Comment: Thank you Aduguid for this very precise answer :) 
Actually, I knew this is the "normal" way of doing it, but as I have something like 56.000 references to make, I was looking for some way to do it automatically to speed it up. 
I was hoping, there is a way to tell Excel to use the one reference it already knows about and to convert it into a bookmark. Or if not this way, maybe there is something like a formula I could drag to the bottom of my tables to insert a bookmark?

Comment: Have you tried to record the actions as a macro? Then you might be able to loop through the column.

Comment: I did, but I can't find a way to click on any cell from the hyperlink-window as I could from a formula-window. So either I write them all manually, or... I don't know?

Comment: Do you know if there is a formula to do that kind of thing?

Comment: Can you try `=HYPERLINK("#A1", "Go to cell A1")`?

Comment: Thank you :) It doesn't work, I get an error message "the formula contains an error" and it points to #A1. In the meanwhile, I found a VBA code that might work, but I need more insight on it, maybe you could help?

Comment: Here is the code: 
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Select Case Target.Address
Case "$C$6"
Sheets("A").Visible = True
Sheets("A").Activate

Case "$C$70"
Sheets("B").Visible = True
Sheets("B").Activate
End Select
End Sub

Comment: Anyway, my problem is that the code work only for the mentionned cells. I don't know how to make it work for the range C6:C69, for example. I tried to write just that, but is doesn't work. Then I tried replacing "case" with "range" and it doesn't work. I'm sure there is a way to enter a range in there, but I really don't know how...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any easy way to do it inside Excel. One way could be to select all the values and then do the normal way, i.e. a range of cells will get the same hyperlink reference. For individual cells, it's the tedious Ctrl + K and apply it manually.

However, this will speed up things. This will make all your cell reference to clickable hyperlinks, based on their cell values (or more specific, cell reference/"formula" reference), by looping through columns and cells.

- Code will unhide all sheets that are not visible to prevent broken links.
- Unfilter all data.
- Then we loop columns. `For j = 3 To 4` -> means we loop from Column C to Column D, if you need to loop more columns, just add numbers.
- For each column we loop through the rows. `For i = 6 To lrow` -> we loop from row 6 to last row (`lrow`).
- I didn't use sheet reference in code, so only have the sheet you want apply code to selected in Excel and run the code (`ActiveSheet.`).

The hyperlink function only accepts link references like `A$D2`, but when we select a cell we have a cell reference like: `=A!$D2`. So the code with replace lines will remove `=`, `$` characters.

**VBA Code**

```
Sub AddMultipleHyperlinksByCellReference()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'First make all worksheets visible/unhidden to prevent broken links.
Next ws

Dim lrow As Long
Dim myString As String
Dim myNewString As String
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long

If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then 'Check if any filter is applied
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData 'Unhide all filterering if filter is on
End If

For j = 3 To 4 'Loop from Column 3 and 4 (Column C and D)
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in current sheet
    For i = 6 To lrow 'Loop from row 6 to Last row
        myString = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j)).Formula 'Get current cells reference i.e. =A!$D2
        myNewString = Replace(myString, "=", "") 'Remove "=" character from string i.e. A!$D2
        myNewString = Replace(myNewString, "$", "") 'Remove "$" character from string i.e. A!D2, this is the value SubAddress will accept as link reference
        'Below part creates the actually link according to the row "i", column "j" and uses the variable "myNewString" as link reference
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j)), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                                   myNewString
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

***Don't forget to make a backup copy of your workbook, and then apply the macro.*** If a worksheet is hidden and you click on the link it will appear as the link doesn't work...

**Result:**

[image]

---

As you have discovered, you can avoid hyperlinks (hyperlinks will be exact!, so they will direct you to a specific cell) and just redirect to worksheets. I made a small attempt but the behavior is not as desired... I think CASE is for individual values (Cell A2 = 1) or ranges (from 10 to 20)... not for cell ranges.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$B$2" To "B$11"
        Sheets("A").Visible = True
        Sheets("A").Activate
        Case "$C$2:$C$10" 'This second statement will never be executed, since CASE only take the first part... I think you need to loop the selected range to make it execute..
        Sheets("B").Visible = True
        Sheets("B").Activate
End Select
End Sub
```

### ---------------------------

Hide sheets:

Since you want to hide columns on another sheet than you currently visit, we need to specify which worksheet you want to affect.

So hide Column C to Column D for Worksheet "A".

```
Worksheets("A").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet A
```

However, that code will give you an error if the sheet already have the specific columns hidden..

Therefore we add this line before the code above (Unhide all columns in worksheet "A"):

```
Worksheets("A").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet A
```

This needs to be done for all worksheets letter and for all the combinations (FR&EN, FR&DE, FR&SP).

**Complete code:**

```
Sub Hide_Spanish_And_English()
'Hide Spanish And English Columns for all Letter Sheet

Worksheets("A").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet A
Worksheets("B").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet B
Worksheets("C").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet C
Worksheets("D").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet D
Worksheets("E").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet E
Worksheets("F").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet F
Worksheets("G").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet G
Worksheets("H").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet H
Worksheets("I").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet I
Worksheets("J").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet J
Worksheets("K").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet K
Worksheets("L").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet L
Worksheets("M").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet M
Worksheets("N").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet N
Worksheets("O").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet O
Worksheets("P").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet P
Worksheets("Q").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Q
Worksheets("R").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet R
Worksheets("S").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet S
Worksheets("T").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet T
Worksheets("U").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet U
Worksheets("V").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet V
Worksheets("W").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet W
Worksheets("X").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet X
Worksheets("Y").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Y
Worksheets("Z").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Z
Worksheets("A").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet A
Worksheets("B").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet B
Worksheets("C").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet C
Worksheets("D").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet D
Worksheets("E").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet E
Worksheets("F").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet F
Worksheets("G").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet G
Worksheets("H").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet H
Worksheets("I").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet I
Worksheets("J").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet J
Worksheets("K").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet K
Worksheets("L").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet L
Worksheets("M").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet M
Worksheets("N").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet N
Worksheets("O").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet O
Worksheets("P").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet P
Worksheets("Q").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet Q
Worksheets("R").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet R
Worksheets("S").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet S
Worksheets("T").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet T
Worksheets("U").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet U
Worksheets("V").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet V
Worksheets("W").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet W
Worksheets("X").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet X
Worksheets("Y").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet Y
Worksheets("Z").Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and English for Sheet Z

End Sub

Sub Hide_English_And_German()
'Hide English And German Columns for all Letter Sheet

Worksheets("A").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet A
Worksheets("B").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet B
Worksheets("C").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet C
Worksheets("D").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet D
Worksheets("E").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet E
Worksheets("F").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet F
Worksheets("G").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet G
Worksheets("H").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet H
Worksheets("I").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet I
Worksheets("J").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet J
Worksheets("K").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet K
Worksheets("L").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet L
Worksheets("M").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet M
Worksheets("N").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet N
Worksheets("O").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet O
Worksheets("P").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet P
Worksheets("Q").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Q
Worksheets("R").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet R
Worksheets("S").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet S
Worksheets("T").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet T
Worksheets("U").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet U
Worksheets("V").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet V
Worksheets("W").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet W
Worksheets("X").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet X
Worksheets("Y").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Y
Worksheets("Z").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Z
Worksheets("A").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet A
Worksheets("B").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet B
Worksheets("C").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet C
Worksheets("D").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet D
Worksheets("E").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet E
Worksheets("F").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet F
Worksheets("G").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet G
Worksheets("H").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet H
Worksheets("I").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet I
Worksheets("J").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet J
Worksheets("K").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet K
Worksheets("L").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet L
Worksheets("M").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet M
Worksheets("N").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet N
Worksheets("O").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet O
Worksheets("P").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet P
Worksheets("Q").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet Q
Worksheets("R").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet R
Worksheets("S").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet S
Worksheets("T").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet T
Worksheets("U").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet U
Worksheets("V").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet V
Worksheets("W").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet W
Worksheets("X").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet X
Worksheets("Y").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet Y
Worksheets("Z").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide English and German for Sheet Z

End Sub

Sub Hide_Spanish_And_German()
'Hide Spanish And German Columns for all Letter Sheet

Worksheets("A").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet A
Worksheets("B").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet B
Worksheets("C").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet C
Worksheets("D").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet D
Worksheets("E").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet E
Worksheets("F").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet F
Worksheets("G").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet G
Worksheets("H").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet H
Worksheets("I").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet I
Worksheets("J").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet J
Worksheets("K").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet K
Worksheets("L").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet L
Worksheets("M").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet M
Worksheets("N").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet N
Worksheets("O").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet O
Worksheets("P").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet P
Worksheets("Q").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Q
Worksheets("R").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet R
Worksheets("S").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet S
Worksheets("T").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet T
Worksheets("U").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet U
Worksheets("V").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet V
Worksheets("W").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet W
Worksheets("X").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet X
Worksheets("Y").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Y
Worksheets("Z").Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide everything in Sheet Z
Worksheets("A").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet A
Worksheets("B").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet B
Worksheets("C").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet C
Worksheets("D").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet D
Worksheets("E").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet E
Worksheets("F").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet F
Worksheets("G").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet G
Worksheets("H").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet H
Worksheets("I").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet I
Worksheets("J").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet J
Worksheets("K").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet K
Worksheets("L").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet L
Worksheets("M").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet M
Worksheets("N").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet N
Worksheets("O").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet O
Worksheets("P").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet P
Worksheets("Q").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet Q
Worksheets("R").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet R
Worksheets("S").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet S
Worksheets("T").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet T
Worksheets("U").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet U
Worksheets("V").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet V
Worksheets("W").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet W
Worksheets("X").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet X
Worksheets("Y").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet Y
Worksheets("Z").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Spanish and German for Sheet Z

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Wizhi :) 
Thank you again - seems you're going to be something like my Excel-Angel ;) 

I've just tried this macro with a test-workbook and a copy of my original workbook, but it doesn't work... So I've tried to copy-paste it into the code-sheet of the one sheet I want it applied to, no change. The same for "this workbook" or classic modules in visual basic editor. 
I also tried to apply an active sheet to it "with sheet ("Synthèse FR&EN") Visible = True Activate", but it doesn't work either.
I'm doing something wrong, but what? Do you happen to have an idea about that too?

Comment: No problem, I like to help :)!! And I think the environment here could be more supportive ;), is fun that all kind of people are here and we should protect that more, opinion. The first code should work... :P. It sounds strange, should work with the classic modules in vba... I [share](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ivzpwwbnl7phbe/Book1.1.xlsm?dl=0) a mock example with you so you can see my setup and how I [pasted my in module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSPSc.png), let me know if it still doesn't work :). FYI, I couldn't get the 2nd code to work, will try to post question and see if it's possible.

Comment: Thank you :) I downloaded it tried, but even though I can see the code and understand the logic, it remains inert - or at least, there is no visible effect to it, and the data in the first sheet remain inactive.

Comment: Right now, I've proceeded differently, with another code that sends me to the selected sheet when double-clicking on a cell. Unfortunately, it can only send be to one specific cell in this sheet, but it's not such a problem as long as I am indeed on the right sheet ;)

Comment: But now.... I'm struggling with this option to "hide column on dectivating the source sheet", and it's quite unnerving how little I understand VBA... I'm trying to learn, but it takes a lot of time and I need this one file to be ready quite quickly. As you say, I was sent on my way on other places in this forum, but well, cannot be angry at them as their are basically true: I should learn and not become everything premade if I am to get anything useful from this ;)

Comment: As long it works for you, I'm happy :). Just let me know if you need any help or if I can do anything and I will be more than happy to look into it!! I think encouragement is important too. You notice quite fast people who wants to learn and trying vs. people who demand/put no effort at all. You are clearly the former :) and I think there are too few of them, and that's sad. I also like the cause of your project!! Don't give up, you'll make it. But, the more you learn, the more you always realize how little you know... :P

Comment: Thank you :) Yes, I hope I am one of those people able to learn... But I'm still stuck with the functionnality of hiding columns on exit. That's stupid, really... I tried putting my code in a standard module, doesn't word, in the source or target sheet, doesn't work either. So I'm clearly missing something, or maybe it's my worksheet as your own code didn't work either, I'm unsure. How would you do it?

Comment: :D, _"functionnality of hiding columns on exit"_, I'm sorry, I don't follow. Please describe what you want to do (expected result) and I will be more than happy to look into it :)!!

Comment: Sorry, I was quite tired and in a hurry that day ;) 

I am trying to figure out how to hide specific columns on a target sheet when the user exits the source sheet. More specifically, when the user exits (deactivates ;)) "Synthèse FR&EN" sheet and goes to the letter-sheet "A", for example, I want to hide all columns that are not related to French or English terms. 
Not sure this is much clearer, actually...

Comment: Np ;), Could be me that have a hard time to understand too :D. Yes, I see what you want to do. I don't know how your code for "deactivate and go to letter-sheet A" looks, but in that code you could add the code I updated my answer with. // Another approach would to paste this code in the buttons of the "Sommaire_XY" sheets (where you select your target language). Since the user choose the language direction already there. Anything unclear just ask :)!

Comment: Are you aware you just saved my week? I will be able to stop digging through the web for the right syntax, that's symply wonderful :D:D 
I just added "Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()" and could copy/paste it into the code of the selected sheets - THANK YOU !!!!!!

Comment: And now I'm trying to find out how to hide non-adjacent columns, like C & E. So I tried Worksheets("A").Columns("C" & "E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True, and Worksheets("A").Columns("C") AND ("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True, and then Worksheets("A").Columns("C") & ("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True, and it all failed. 
VBA accepted the code Worksheets("A").Columns("C" & "E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True, but won't actually run it. I don't get any error warning, it's just that plain nothing happens. Could you help me further please ?

Comment: And btw... how do you display the code the way you did, in a kind of integrated frame?

Comment: Np, glad to help :D!! Glad it worked. Strange that you don't get error. Of course I will hep you :)! // This code will let you hide non-adjacent cells `Worksheets("A").Range("C1,E1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`. In the comment field it's " ` " before and after the word. In the answer you have small this symbol {}. Highlight code and click on that and text will be represented as code.

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEES!!! Thank you :D:D Now the file stands and works very well :) All that remains is to fill it with words & definitions. 
Here it is if you wish to see it ;) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovhsz2vd1xxsutg/Fiche%20terminologique_Backup_V8.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Yeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaa. Its really good :D!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you for showing me, really fun to see. // I'm happy for you and very very impressed by your solution of re-direct to another sheet. Better than my suggestion :)!! Well done!!! You have learn so much and made a very wonderful work. Feel proud because you should :) // I went through your sheet and I want to give you two comments. 1. I think you need to update the code for the following sheets: `DEANGL` & `ANGLGERM`. `They still have Columns("B,D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` instead of `Range("B1,D1")` which give me an error.

Comment: 2. You can decrease your workbook size and make it faster. Reason is that worksheets like ANGLSPA, ANGLFRA and Synthèse_FR&SP are based on the same template. You had about 11k rows from the beginning and then you cleared the ones you didn't need. However, the formatting is still left!! You can easily see that by looking at the row height. [The formatting ends and the row height will decrease](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cls7x.png). Delete all the rows below your table will reset the cells to default. This means that excel doesn't need to recalculate those cells. Smaller file and faster workbook.

Comment: I made a short [demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3ZAY.gif) to show you the above point (2). // Can't emphasize enough, amazing work!!!!!!! I know how much time and effort that you have put into it so it's really fun to see how you managed it. So happy and a lot of thanks for showing the file. Really fun too see!!!! :D.

Comment: Bug testing here ;) [I will try your worksheet and see if I find more, hope that's ok]. Sheet ANGLSPA, is missing line `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D69")) Is Nothing Then` in the beginning of the code.

Comment: Hi again :) Thank you for new tips & tricks - I've implemented the changes and the file indeed has decreased in size ! :D

Comment: Hi :)!, No problem!! Nice to hear that the size decrease. oohh, the code should be: `Worksheets("A").Range("B1,D1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Comment: I've going through your file again :). Double check sheet "DEFRA". Might missing code `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D69")) Is Nothing Then`. Rest of code executes for me :)! // The button "Ecology" is not assigned to a macro on several sheets. The other (Global Context and Cinema is)

Comment: Thank you very much again Wizhi - it's been quite some time now, but I just went through the file again and corrected this and some other little bugs lying around - now it seems to work just fine - and that's in a very big part thanks to your help!! :D

Comment: Glad it worked and a wonderful work made by you, you did a lot too. Both effort and time wise, be proud of that :)!! I'm very happy that I could be a little part of your project and give you feedback. Thanks for your kind words, means a lot to me :). Hope you come across more here, it has been really fun :D!! Best wishes //Jonathan S

Comment: Thank you :D Well, in fact i'll come back to your proposal, as I would like to enhance file by adding a better browsing function: right now, the user may click on a work in the "Sommaire"-sheet, and is sent on to the letter-sheet the word comes from (hope that is clear). What I would like is either for the user to user precisely onto the one cell the word is written in, and then to hide all the lines around a specific table. I know now how to hide lines and columns, but I don't how to send the user to the right cell... Any idea?

Comment: Hi :) :)!, sorry for late reply!, The only thing I can think of is to is hyperlink, I don't know of any other way. You already have the code in your workbook. In the vba module: `Général` you have the sub code. `Sub AddMultipleHyperlinksByCellReference()`. Everytime a user clicks the link it will direct the user to the specific cell. However, I wonder if it's possible to hide rows /column when you click the hyperlink... not to sure about that, nothing I'm aware of after checking around a bit.

Comment: I made a [demo to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxIKS.gif) you how I use the code in your workbook. The video is quite fast since there is a upload size limit. :). Steps are: // 1. Go to the correct sheet you want to apply the code (example is SPAFRA). // 2. Unfilter the table // 3. Then execute the code.

Comment: While I wrote this I asked myself... how can a user from the "Sommaire"-sheet be directed to the letter sheet, I don't follow that? Your code `If Not Intersect(Target, ...` are applied only on the target sheets (`DESPA`, `SPADE`, etc..) and therefore the code should only be triggered when the user double-click on those worksheets. No other sheets should be affected... strange :P